# Problems with Upgrade to Python3

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

I updated my Mac to Python 3.4.3, I changed my interpreter in PyCharm to be Python 3.4.3. When I try to run a test, it looks like it is still using Python 2.7.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 331, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/curtis.salisbury/Documents/local_copy/trunk/automation/selenium/src/tests/framework/test_ddt.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base_framework import BaseFramework
  File "/Users/curtis.salisbury/Documents/local_copy/trunk/automation/selenium/src/tests/framework/base_framework.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tests.base_test_case import BaseTestCase
  File "/Users/curtis.salisbury/Documents/local_copy/trunk/automation/selenium/src/tests/base_test_case.py", line 7, in <module>
    import http.client
ImportError: No module named http.client
```

What am I missing here to make this work in Python 3? I tried using an alias in terminal and when I do that, the interpreter changes to Python 3, however, when I run in PyCharm, it goes back to the 2.7?

Comment: Please make sure that Python 3 is selected in PyCharm | Preferences | Project: <your project name> | Project Interpreter.

Comment: It is the only interpreter listed in there.

Comment: How exactly are you running your test?

Answer (score 1):

I went into Edit Configurations and for some reason the interpreter in there was still Python 2. I changed it over to 3 and it worked superbly.